# Protect entire workbook with multiple sheet via a macro

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I want to protect entire workbook which have multiple sheets. Protection needs to be applied on all the sheets as well. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can start from here:

```
Sub protect()
Dim s As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
s = InputBox("Enter Password", "Protection", "")
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.protect s
Next ws
ThisWorkbook.protect s
End Sub

Sub unprotect()
Dim s As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
s = InputBox("Enter Password", "Protection", "")
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.unprotect s
Next ws
ThisWorkbook.unprotect s
End Sub
```

Change for use with other workbooks and/or passwords.

Comment: Faster in what sense?

Comment: instead of applying FOR loop and going one by one for each sheet, can we do it directly with some function? I have a very big excel file with 63 tabs, applying this loop will take time to run the macro.

Comment: Have you tried it? You enter the password only once. So the **for** loop should run pretty fast.